# Pasar parámetros a traves de redirect desde el controlador con laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hola ¿cómo puedo redireccionar a una vista y además pasar un mensaje desde el controlador hasta la vista? Tengo un problema con dos formularios `patch` y hasta ahora la solución ha sido redireccionando pero necesito pasar un parámetro `$mensaje='estado actualizado'` lo que he conseguido es esto:

```
Return redirect(action('MaitenenceController@device_details',$id))->with($message);
```

Pero no logro que se me muestre el `alert`  uso esta condición :

```
if( isset ($_GET['message'])){
}
```

Comment: la expresion que usas en el if, en laravel no funciona de esa manera ya que laravel provee un version simplificada de esto, tu mensaje esta bien enviado pero al recibirli en el alert es donde esta el error

Comment: Si gracias , ese fue el error en el if debía de usar session ('message')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`with` necesita 2 parámetros

> ->with("message",$message);

y para mostrarlo necesitas invocar a la variable globar `session`

```
@if(session('message'))
  <div class="alert alert-success">
    {{ session('message') }}
  </div>
@endif
```

dentro del `if else` puedes poner script tambien con `notify js`

```
<script src="{{url('assets/js/notify.js')}}"></script>
@if(session('message'))
 <script>
  $.notify("{{session('message')}}",{
    className:"success",
    globalPosition: "top center"
  });
</script>
@endif
```

cuya libreria tendras que descargarla, y agregar mediante `@push`

Answer (score 1):

#### Redireccionar a la vista pasando un mensaje

Enviar por ejemplo un mensaje de error:

```
$route = 'login';
$message = 'This is an error message';

return redirect($route)
    ->with('error', $message);
```

a la vista anterior:

```
return redirect()
    ->back()
    ->with('error', $message);
```

y usando la acción del controlador:

```
$id = ['id' => 1]; // ejemplo, si la ID fuera 1
return redirect()
    ->action('MaitenenceController@device_details', $id)
    ->with('error', $message);
```

#### Recuperar el mensaje en la vista

Para recuperar el mensaje en la vista se puede usar el *helper* `session()` directamente, por ejemplo imprimir el mensaje usando *Blade*:

```
@if (session()->has('error')) {{-- comprueba si existe el valor en sesión --}}
    <div class="error">
        <p> {{ session('error') }} </p> {{-- devuelve e imprime el valor de la sesión --}}
    </div>

    {!! session()->forget('error') !!} {{-- borrar el error de sesión --}}
@endif
```

#### Referencias:

[Documentación de *Session* en Laravel 5.8](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#retrieving-data)
[Documentación *Redirect* en Laravel 5.8](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#redirects)

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar Session para poner los mensajes, ejemplo:

> Session::flash('message', ['type' => 'success', 'msg' => 'Mensaje']);
>   return Redirect::action('MaitenenceController@device_details', $id)

saludos

Answer (score 0):

Con la session de message puedes hacerlo, aquí un ejemplo del controlador:

```
return redirect()->route('config')
                 ->with(['message'=>'Estado actualizado correctamente']);
```

Y en la vista puedes poner esto:

```
@if(session('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('message') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

- Esto teniendo en cuenta que tienes un `route` con un name, sino,
  puedes poner `view('nombre de la vista').`
- Igual, en donde dice
  'Estado actualizado correctamente', lo puedes sustituir por una
  variable o concatenar una.